# Ruby/Rails - Models Named with Two Words (Naming Convention Issues)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, naming-conventions

This is really a question about naming conventions.

I have a model called PromotedEvents

The file is called promoted_events.rb

I created the table with:

```
create_table :promoted_events do |t|
```

Now I'm having problems creating anything, so I'm wondering if theres some problem using model with two words

im in the console and tried

```
a = PromotedEvents.new

a = Promoted_Event.new

a = promoted_event.new
```

and keep getting a `nameerror : uninitialized constant` error

Any ideas?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Your class should be singlular.

Name it `PromotedEvent` in the file `promoted_event.rb`

```
a = PromotedEvent.new
```

Comment: What is the terminal command to create a 2 word model? is it `rails generate model Model_Name` or some other combination? Are both words supposed to be capitalized? Do I put the underscore when generating the model?

Comment: I think you can use either `ModelName` or `model_name`, and the right magic will happen.  But `Model_Name` is not right (camel case or underscores, not ever both).  Think of it like creating the model class, so it would be singular since it has to match the class name.

Comment: Yes, @AlexWayne is right. Both `CamelCase` or `under_score` usage is correct according to the [model generator description](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/model/USAGE).

Answer (score 22):

Model names are singular and camel case like so `pe = PromotedEvent.new()`

the file should be  `promoted_event.rb`

Controllers are plural

`PromotedEventsController`

constants are `ALL_CAPS`

locals are `separated_by_underscores_and_lowercase`

table names are plural 'SELECT * FROM promoted_events`

Comment: what about attributes within the model. i.e. rails g model PromotedEvent name_of_event:string --------------> or should it be NameOfEvent:string ? any ideas of what is the syntax is here ?

Comment: it should be just name:string, but if you need two or more words they are lowercase and separated by underscores, i.e. promotional_code:integer

Answer (score 10):

If it helps, I always think of it like this:

The model name is singular because it represents a single, *specific* thing. So, `PromotedEvent` is a specific promoted event that has a name, date, etc.

The table name on the other hand is plural. This is because the table stores a *collection* of these singular items. So, promoted_events.

In rails, filenames are mostly a matter of convention since ruby has pretty lax rules in this regard, but generally it's `class_name.rb`. [This page](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7) might help you get a better overview of what conventions are used where and what is specific to Ruby versus Rails.

Answer (score 1):

If you are an extreme rails n00b like me, then you will want to remember to create a class definition for your newly created table and place it in app/models.

It would go like

```
class LargeCat < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :zoo
end
```